# Meteor dynamically show template the simple way

Tags: meteor

What is the least code / very simple way to dynamically show a html element "the meteor way"? Jquery.show() is very simple but doesn't work and it seems odd that Meteor way requires lines and lines of code? Any suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [UI.dynamic](http://docs.meteor.com/#ui_dynamic). There's a really good example of how to do it in [this post](http://meteorcapture.com/simple-modal-pattern/) on creating a simple modal. Here are the relevant snippets:

```html
<template name="modal">  
  {{#if activeModal}}
    <div class="modal">
      {{> UI.dynamic template=activeModal}}
    </div>
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

```js
Template.modal.helpers({  
  activeModal: function() {
    return Session.get('activeModal');
  }
});
```

Comment: Also, am I right in thinking that there is no way iron router can achieve something similar?

Comment: Under the hood IR uses `UI.dynamic` for rendering the layout. If you mean rendering a portion of the view, the closest thing I can think of is a [yield template](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/DOCS.md#using-a-layout-with-yields), but I'm unclear if those can be dynamic.